# Does browser restriction affect web crawler?

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-4, web-crawler

I'm making site with normal mode and deprecated browser mode, where if someone enters www.mysite.com his user agent goes trough something like this:

```
            // Mobile
            if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) return Redirect("/m");

            // Tabļet
            if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("BlackBerry") || (Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPhone") || (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Android")))) return Redirect("/t");

            // Deprecated
            if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Convert.ToInt32(Request.Browser.Version) < 9) return Redirect("/h");

            // Normaļ
            return View();
```

**Question:** If I restrict some browsers access to my main view, will it restrict access to web crawler as well?

Comment: Relevant (up to and including the alt text): http://xkcd.com/1174/ ;-)

Comment: @delnan well I have main version with css3 transforms and what not, and I hav simplyfied version for older browsers (full compatibility), and then I have separate version for tablet viewers and mobile viewers. This site is more like what can I do not what is the best solution.

Comment: I'm mostly talking about redirecting to `/m`, `/t`, etc. (thus turning `example.com/direct/link/tostuff#!i/want` into `example.com/m#sucks-to-be-you` IIUC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on crawler. Normally all major crawlers like google etc,  just respect robots.txt and rest all should be crawlable. Unless some one has written a poolerly coded crawler it should not affect your site crawling. You can also try crawling your own site using nutch, open source webcrawler.

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day - mister/missis!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple web crawler to crawl mcdonald's websites. What the crawler grabbed every time are mobile web pages. So, for simple crawlers, your setting would restrict access. But major web crawlers don't have this problem.